# sql while loop with date counter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, loops, while-loop

I need to do something like this in sql:

```
declare @StartDate varchar(10)
declare @EndDate varchar(10)
set @StartDate='12/31/2008'
set @EndDate='1/11/2009'

Declare @date varchar = @StartDate
while (@date <= @EndDate)
begin
 -- some statements
set @date += 1 -- basically increment by 1 day
end
```

How can I do the above correctly in SQL?  Basically, my startdate and enddate are strings and not datetimes because my business logic is referencing string column in another table with a date as the name of the column-But I need to loop through a bunch of columns, each column having the name of the next day's date.

If the date is 11/07/2009, the name of the column would be '11/7/2009' (without the 0 in the 7), so I have to watch out for that too.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.  I posted another question specifically about the datetime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the date params to datetime.

```
SELECT convert(datetime, @StartDate) into datetimevariable
```

then you can use date functions to add days.

```
select DATEADD(day,1,datetimevariable) into datetimevariable
```

As a solution to get a m/d/yyyy format, I C&P this function from some website a couple of weeks ago. Use this code to create a function and call in this way:

```
 SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (@DateTimeVariable, 'M/DD/YYYY') into stringVariable
```

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CustomFormatDate (@Datetime DATETIME, @FormatMask VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS VARCHAR(32)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @StringDate VARCHAR(32)
    SET @StringDate = @FormatMask
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘YYYY’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘YYYY’,
                         DATENAME(YY, @Datetime))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘YY’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘YY’,
                         RIGHT(DATENAME(YY, @Datetime),2))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘Month’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘Month’,
                         DATENAME(MM, @Datetime))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘MON’,@StringDate COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)>0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘MON’,
                         LEFT(UPPER(DATENAME(MM, @Datetime)),3))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘Mon’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘Mon’,
                                     LEFT(DATENAME(MM, @Datetime),3))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘MM’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘MM’,
                  RIGHT(‘0′+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MM, @Datetime)),2))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘M’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘M’,
                         CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MM, @Datetime)))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘DD’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘DD’,
                         RIGHT(‘0′+DATENAME(DD, @Datetime),2))
    IF (CHARINDEX (‘D’,@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, ‘D’,
                                    DATENAME(DD, @Datetime))   

RETURN @StringDate
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do you convert from datetime to varchar with a particular format:

declare @StartDate datetime
set @StartDate='12/07/2008'

declare @StartDateString varchar(10)
How do you set @StartDateString to equal '12/7/2008' 

Thanks!

Comment: you can call to convert to cast from datetime to string with a third param. This param is an int that tell the format. Please check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  Unfortunately, 101 is the closest format   mm/dd/yyyy, but I need m/d/yyyy

Comment: I edited my answer to append a solution for the m/d/yyyy format, and others. If you're iterested in performance, modify the function  to convert the date to m/d/yyy only. Will be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx), then [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) it back to a string using the format of choice, like 101 in your case:

```
set @date = convert(varchar(30), dateadd(day,1, @date), 101);
```

Answer (score 1):

i would prefere the way like Jonathan allready said but use datetime variables for the loop and add a day with the DATEADD function. To access the columns you may use the CONVERT or CAST statement but now to get a varchar e.g.: CAST(@date as varchar(10)). If special formatting is needed you can build such a construct like cast(day(@date) as varchar(2)) + '/' + cast(month(@date) as varchar(2)) + '/' + cast(year(@date) as varchar(4)) this would eliminate the '0' as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DECLARE @sd DATETIME
DECLARE @ed DATETIME
SELECT @sd = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-08-23')
SELECT @ed = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-03-21')

DECLARE @date DATETIME = @sd
WHILE ( @date <= @ed )
  BEGIN
      -- some statements
      SELECT @date
      SELECT @date = Dateadd(day, 1, @date)
  END
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.